# return promise from a function called in settimeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout, es6-promise

The following code gives me an error stating `getConfigDetails`...then is not a function. I want to return a promise from the function `getConfigDetails` if the `isConfigLoaded` variable is set to true otherwise keep calling it untill it is.

```
var getConfigDetails = function () {
    if ($rootScope.isconfigloaded) {
        configDetails.roles = $rootScope.orgConfig.roles.slice();
        configDetails.departments = $rootScope.orgConfig.departments.slice();
        configDetails.levels = $rootScope.orgConfig.levels.slice();
        configDetails.designation = $rootScope.orgConfig.designation.slice();
        return Promise.resolve();
     } else {
        setTimeout(function(){
            getConfigDetails();
        },200);
     }
};

getConfigDetails().then(function(){});
```

Comment: use `return $timeout(...)` instead, it returns a Promise. Also try using `$q` service for Promises

Comment: Make a promise from the timeout, and then *chain* the `getConfigDetails` call to it using `then`

Comment: @Bergi  could you explain with an example?

Comment: @ManavChawla `new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200)).then(getConfigDetails)` is a promise chain that you can `return`

Comment: @Bergi i am not sure i follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
var getConfigDetails = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  var ticker = setInterval(function(){
    if ($rootScope.isconfigloaded) {
        //the other stuff
        clearInterval(ticker);
        resolve();
    }
  }, 200);
});
```

You should be able to use it like `getConfigDetails.then(function(){})`

Notice its not a function though, just a promise. If you really want it to be a function do the following:

```
function getConfigDetails() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var ticker = setInterval(function(){
      if ($rootScope.isconfigloaded) {
          //the other stuff
          clearInterval(ticker);
          resolve();
      }
    }, 200);
});
```